# Using WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback in my init state issue +flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

I have a widget 'A' which is called as one of the tab in tab bar view. I am passing a valuenotifier closeDialog from the parent widget to the widget A like this :

```
ValueNotifier<bool> closeDialog = ValueNotifier(false);
```

In the widget A I have init like this:

```
   @override
 void initState() {
//close dialog is added to close the dialog after showing it once
if (widget.showDialog && widget.closeDialog!.value == false) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
              title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.bookingAlert),
             
            );
      },
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        widget.closeDialog!.value = true;
      });
    });
  });
}
super.initState();
 }
```

In this the showdialog variable will be true if the navigation is from a particular route.
When I enter this parent screen from that particular route where showdialog is true, I have to get a alert dialog .

The result I am getting is - two alert dialogs overlapped over each other.

When I add print statement , I can see that the initstate is called twice . I have checked by removing all the code and only adding print in initstate and it is working fine.

I guess the problem occurs with this "WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback".
Can someone help me solve this issue

Comment: can you please provide more code.  where do you use `ValueNotifier<bool> closeDialog = ValueNotifier(false);` since you call by widget.closeDialog ?  if its local variable, you should not called with `widget.___`

Comment: @pmatatias I am initializing it in the parent widget and passing it to the widget A as a constructor